# VBA xlSpecifiedTables Not Pulling Specified Tables in 2016 Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have many macros built with the following type of code:

```
.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
.WebTables = """AutoNumber1"", ""AutoNumber5"""
```

These macros work perfectly fine in Excel 2007, and used to work perfectly fine in Excel 2016. Recently, the Excel 2016 version will pull the entire page instead of the specified tables, and will additionally pull the formatting from the web page. It never did these things before, and functionality of the exact same file in Excel 2007 remains the same.

I have also re-recorded a macro in Excel 2016 and selected a specific table via Get External Data From Web, and the code is reproduced exactly as above, but it still pulls the entire page.

I am aware that I can manually reorganize the data after the pull and there are also Queries, but I would really prefer to know why SpecifiedTables no long pulls specified tables. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)